# Why can't I get annotation @Database in RoomDatabase

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite, android-room

I want to get a `Map<String, Class<?>>` to get all table name and entity. But stuck by:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'java.lang.Class[] androidx.room.Database.entities()' on a null object reference
at com.aum.samplemvvm.repository.database.TravelDB.getTables(TravelDB.java:32)
```

## My Class:

```
package com.aum.samplemvvm.repository.database;

import android.database.Cursor;

import androidx.room.Database;
import androidx.room.Entity;
import androidx.room.RoomDatabase;
import androidx.sqlite.db.SupportSQLiteDatabase;

import com.aum.samplemvvm.repository.database.entities.ImageMemo;
import com.aum.samplemvvm.repository.database.entities.KeyNIM;
import com.aum.samplemvvm.repository.database.entities.Note;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

@Database(entities = {Note.class, ImageMemo.class, KeyNIM.class}, version = 3, exportSchema = false)
public abstract class TravelDB extends RoomDatabase {

    public abstract TravelDAO travelDAO();

    /**
     * Get all entities table
     *
     * @return map entities, Map<tableName, Class<Entity>>
     */
    public Map<String, Class<?>> getTables() {
        Map<String, Class<?>> entityMap = new HashMap<>();
        Database database = TravelDB.class.getAnnotation(Database.class);
        Class<?>[] entities = database.entities();
        for (Class<?> entity : entities) {
            String tableName = entity.getAnnotation(Entity.class).tableName();
            entityMap.put(tableName, entity);
        }
        return entityMap;
    }

    /**
     * @return List all table name, include system table
     */
    public List<String> getAllTables() {
        List<String> tableNames = new ArrayList<>();
        SupportSQLiteDatabase db = getOpenHelper().getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.query("SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table'", new String[]{});
        try {
            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
...
}
```

I want a `Map<String, Class<?>>` as `<tableName, Entity>`.